# Unable to create more than two table using sync_table() in cqlengine

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, cqlengine

I have the following class in python and am using cqlengine as object mapper for cassandra DB,

```
class Company(Model):
    id = columns.Integer(index=True, primary_key=True)
    company_name = columns.Text(required=False)
    created_at = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.now)

class Social(Model):
    id = columns.Integer(index=True, primary_key=True)
    name = columns.Text(required=False)

class UserCompany(Model):
    id = columns.Integer(index=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = columns.Integer(required=True)
    company_id = columns.Integer(required=True)

array_of_tables=[UserCompany, Company, Social]
    for table in array_of_tables:
        sync_table(table)
```

Issue: Am not able to create more than two table in cassandra while executing the code.

Erorr message:

```
  File "test.py", line 109, in <module>
    create_tables()
  File "test.py", line 68, in create_tables
    sync_table(table)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/management.py", line 259, in sync_table
    execute(qs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 171, in execute
    result = session.execute(query, params, timeout=timeout)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1602, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute (cassandra/cluster.c:27334)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3347, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:65206)
cassandra.InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot create secondary index on partition key column id"
```

Need you help in resolving this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cassandra.InvalidRequest: code=2200 \[Invalid query\] message="Cannot create secondary index on partition key column id"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791300/cassandra-invalidrequest-code-2200-invalid-query-message-cannot-create-secon)

Answer (score 0):

Setting index for the primary column is not allowed. I just removed that from the code and it worked. It should look like the below. Here, I just used UUID instead of integer still that's anyway not relevant to the actual issue.

```
class Company(Model):
    id = columns.UUID(default=uuid.uuid1(), primary_key=True))
    company_name = columns.Text(required=False)
    created_at = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.now)

class Social(Model):
    id = columns.UUID(default=uuid.uuid1(), primary_key=True)
    name = columns.Text(required=False)

class UserCompany(Model):
    id = columns.UUID(default=uuid.uuid1(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = columns.Integer(required=True)
    company_id = columns.Integer(required=True)

array_of_tables=[UserCompany, Company, Social]
    for table in array_of_tables:
        sync_table(table)
```